# Suddenly getting undefined symbols (_sqlite3_mprintf) error

Tags: ios, sqlite, linker-errors, linphone

All of a sudden I am getting the following compile error in my project:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_sqlite3_mprintf", referenced from:
      _linphone_core_store_call_log in liblinphone.a(call_log.c.o)
      _linphone_chat_message_store in liblinphone.a(message_storage.c.o)
      _linphone_chat_message_store_state in liblinphone.a(message_storage.c.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Clean, clean build folder, re-build.

Comment: I did that and I get the error on build.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your Xcode project is missing a reference to `sqlite3` that is required by `liblinphone`:

1. Open your Xcode project file
2. Go the "General" tab
3. Look for the section that says "Linked Frameworks and Libraries"
4. Press the "+" button
5. Search for "sqlite"
6. Click on "libsqlite3.dylib" and press "Add"

Now it should build and run.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the new xcode beta version and that fixed it.